# Dust.js how to use @eq to set selected option in template

Tags: html-select, dust.js

I have been experimenting with dust.js by using the home page to create templates (http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/). I am simply trying to set the selected option in a selectbox.  Here is my data model:

```
{
  "name": "SOME NAME",
  "favorite_food": 1,
  "food_options": [{id:1, value: "Ice Cream"},{id:2, value: "Pizza"},{id:3, value:    "Fish"}]
}
```

I would like to set the selected option by matching the id in the food_options array to the favorite_food property. Here is my template:

```
<h1>{name}</h1>
<select>
  {#food_options}
    <option value="{id}"{@eq key=id value=favorite_food}  selected="true"{/eq} >
     {value}
    </option>
  {/food_options}
</select>
```

It seems like it should be simple and I've tried all sorts of variations, but can't get it to work. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The Dust helpers you're hoping for are actually a part of the LinkedIn fork of Dust.js. To be able to use those helpers, try using this site:

http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/test/test.html

LinkedIn fork of Dust:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs

DustJs Helpers:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers

Comment: Problem solved - I guess I was using the wrong page to test my template. When I used this the first link (http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/test/test.html) everything worked as expected. Thanks smfoote!